# when is NSURLConnection's canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace called?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a clustered server in a host that serves my ios client which authenticates against Server Trust authentication method.

Here, the response from a clustered server hits the `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` every time (i.e.,) for every response whereas a response from a non-clustered server hits it only once for a session.

When is this method `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` called? Why does my response hit it every time? What do I have to do further to make the response from a clustered environment behave the same way as it would in a non-clustered environment?